# Returning a 2D array from function to main function

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, conways-game-of-life

I am writting code for Game of Life, and as stipulated for my assigment I am not supposed to use pointers.

For couting the amount of neightbours each cell, cell in this context is a coordinate on my 2D array, I have written a fucntion which goes through all rows and columns and counts how many ALIVE neighbours each cell has. Maximum would be 8.

However I do not know how to return my array which stores the amount neighbouring cells in a 20x20 array.

Below is the entire code. Observe that some parts are unfinished since I am complementing a template given to me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/* Constants, representation of states */
#define ALIVE 'X'
#define DEAD '.'

/* Declaration of data structure */
typedef struct{
  char current;
  char next;
} cell;

/* Declaration of functions */
void initField(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols]);
void loadGlider(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols]);
void loadSemaphore(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols]);
void loadRandom(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols]);
void loadCustom(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols]);
void printWorld(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols]);
int CellNeighbour(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols]);



/* Function:    main
* Description: Start and run games, interact with the user.
* Input:       About what initial structure and whether to step or exit.
* Output:      Information to the user, and the game field in each step.
*/

int main(void) {

  const int rows = 20;
  const int cols = 20;
  cell field[rows][cols];
  int counting[rows][cols];

  initField(rows,cols, field);
  printWorld(rows,cols,field);
  CellNeighbour(rows,cols,field);//test



    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            printf("%d ", counting[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }




  return 0;
}


/* Function:    initField
* Description: Initialize all the cells to dead, then asks the user about
*              which structure to load, and finally load the structure.
* Input:       The field array and its size.
* Output:      The field array is updated.
*/

void initField(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols]) {

  for (int r = 0 ; r < rows ; r++) {
    for (int c = 0 ; c < cols ; c++) {
      field[r][c].current = DEAD;
    }
  }

  printf("Select field spec to load ([G]lider, [S]emaphore, [R]andom ");
  printf("or [C]ustom): ");

  int ch = getchar();

  /* Ignore following newline */
  if (ch != '\n') {
    getchar();
  }

  switch (ch) {
    case 'g':
    case 'G':
    loadGlider(rows, cols, field);
    break;
    case 's':
    case 'S':
    loadSemaphore(rows, cols, field);
    break;
    case 'r':
    case 'R':
    loadRandom(rows, cols, field);
    break;
    case 'c':
    case 'C':
    default:
    loadCustom(rows, cols, field);
    break;
  }
}


/* Function:    loadGlider
* Description: Inserts a glider into the field.
* Input:       The field array and its size.
* Output:      The field array is updated.
*/

void loadGlider(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols]) {

  field[0][1].current = ALIVE;
  field[1][2].current = ALIVE;
  field[2][0].current = ALIVE;
  field[2][1].current = ALIVE;
  field[2][2].current = ALIVE;
}


/* Function:    loadSemaphore
* Description: Inserts a semaphore into the field.
* Input:       The field array and its size.
* Output:      The field array is updated.
*/

void loadSemaphore(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols]) {

  field[8][1].current = ALIVE;
  field[8][2].current = ALIVE;
  field[8][3].current = ALIVE;
}


/* Function:    loadRandom
* Description: Inserts a random structure into the field.
* Input:       The field array and its size.
* Output:      The field array is updated. There is a 50 % chance that a cell
*              is alive.
*/

void loadRandom(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols]) {

}


/* Function:    loadCustom
* Description: Lets the user specify a structure that then is inserted into
*              the field.
* Input:       The field array and its size.
* Output:      The field array is updated.
*/

void loadCustom(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols]) {

  printf("Give custom format string: ");
  do {
    int r, c;
    scanf("%d,%d", &r, &c);
    field[r][c].current = ALIVE;
  } while (getchar() != '\n');
}
/* Function:    printWorld
* Description: Prints the current field
* Input:       The field array and its size.
* Output:      The field array is updated.
*/


void printWorld(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols]){

  char c = '\n';

  while(c == '\n'){
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        printf("%c ", field[i][j].current);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
    c = getchar();
    if(c != '\n'){
      break; // hoppa ut ur loopen till main funktionen
    }

  }
}

void evolve(const int rows,const int cols,cell field[rows][cols]){

  for(int i = 0;i<rows;i++){
    for(int j =0;j<cols;j++){
      if(field[rows][cols].current == ALIVE  && ArrayDatCorresponds2NmbofNeighb[rows][cols]<2){
      }
      if(field[rows][cols].current == ALIVE && ArrayDatCorresponds2NmbofNeighb[rows][cols] ==3 ||ArrayDatCorresponds2NmbofNeighb[rows][cols] ==2 ){
        field[rows][cols].next = ALIVE;
      }
      if(field[rows][cols].current == ALIVE && ArrayDatCorresponds2NmbofNeighb[rows][cols] >= 4 ){
        field[rows][cols].next = DEAD;
      }
      if(field[rows][cols].current == DEAD && ArrayDatCorresponds2NmbofNeighb[rows][cols] ==3){
        field[rows][cols].next = ALIVE;
      }
    }
  }



int CellNeighbour(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols]){

  int i,j;
  int count =0;
  for( i =0;i<rows;i++){
    for( j = 0;j<cols;j++){
  int StoreArray[rows][cols] =0;
 }
}

  for( i =0;i<rows;i++){
    for( j = 0;j<cols;j++){
      if(field[rows-1][cols-1].current == ALIVE){
        StoreArray[i][j]=count++;
      }
      if(field[rows][cols-1].current == ALIVE){
        StoreArray[i][j]=count++;
      }
      if(field[rows+1][cols-1].current == ALIVE){
        StoreArray[i][j]=count++;
      }
      if(field[rows+1][cols].current == ALIVE){
        StoreArray[i][j]=count++;
      }
      if(field[rows+1][cols+1].current == ALIVE){
        StoreArray[i][j]=count++;
      }
      if(field[rows][cols+1].current == ALIVE){
        StoreArray[i][j]=count++;
      }
      if(field[rows-1][cols+1].current == ALIVE){
        StoreArray[i][j]=count++;
      }
      if(field[rows-1][cols].current == ALIVE){
        StoreArray[i][j]=count++;
      }
    }
  }


  return StoreArray; 
}
```

Below is the function which I am having issues with:

```
int CellNeighbour(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols]){

  int i,j;
  int count =0;
  for( i =0;i<rows;i++){
    for( j = 0;j<cols;j++){
  int StoreArray[rows][cols] =0;
 }
}

  for( i =0;i<rows;i++){
    for( j = 0;j<cols;j++){
      if(field[rows-1][cols-1].current == ALIVE){
        StoreArray[i][j]=count++;
      }
      if(field[rows][cols-1].current == ALIVE){
        StoreArray[i][j]=count++;
      }
      if(field[rows+1][cols-1].current == ALIVE){
        StoreArray[i][j]=count++;
      }
      if(field[rows+1][cols].current == ALIVE){
        StoreArray[i][j]=count++;
      }
      if(field[rows+1][cols+1].current == ALIVE){
        StoreArray[i][j]=count++;
      }
      if(field[rows][cols+1].current == ALIVE){
        StoreArray[i][j]=count++;
      }
      if(field[rows-1][cols+1].current == ALIVE){
        StoreArray[i][j]=count++;
      }
      if(field[rows-1][cols].current == ALIVE){
        StoreArray[i][j]=count++;
      }
    }
  }


  return StoreArray; 
}
```

If I initilize a 20x20 field where I have some ALIVE cells.

Then I would expect, after printing out a 5x5(just to make it simple) which calculates how many neighbours each cell has, a grid which looks something like this:

```
2 2 0 0 0
2 3 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: You cannot return array types from a function.  To meet the conditions of your assignment, you will have to pass the target array as a parameter to your functions (i.e., `int CellNeighbour(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols], cell counts[rows][cols])`

Comment: @JohnBode That also requires pointers. So it won't work either.

Comment: The normal way to do this would be to pass a pointer to the array as an argument as John Bode suggests.  The other way is to (ugh) access a global array.

Comment: @NikosC.: Then he can't pass his source arrays to functions either, and I would really question the intent of the assignment if that were really the case.

Comment: @JohnBode They did discourage people from it. Might've been since they have some other method in mind. I could try email lecturer, they're usually not to bad regarding these stuff. How would I then do with a pointer? Declare ``StoreArray`` as a pointer in my main-function and pass it to my ``CellNeighbour`` function?

Comment: I think the best solution here is to make the dimensions global constants so that you don't need to make the array itself global, and also don't need to have arguments on all the functions for the dimensions. You pretty much have to make something global or repeatedly use the same literal ints everywhere which is even worse imo.

Comment: @AliasaZarownyPseudonymia: You just declare a normal 2D array and pass the name - `int store[rows][cols];...CellNeighbour(rows,cols,field,store);`.  The array expressions `field` and `store` are implicitly converted to pointers before being passed to the function.  In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are both "adjusted" to `T *a`, so you can use array declaration syntax for the parameter, but it's still treated as a pointer (this is *only* true for function parameters, though).

Comment: @JohnBode Why wouldn't it count as a pointer though? It is functionally the same.

Comment: @ChrisRollins: It depends on how serious the instructor is about "no pointers".  I *refuse* to believe they meant you couldn't pass array expressions as arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You can't return arrays in C. And since you're not allowed to use pointers, you'll have to wrap the array in a struct. Example:

```
typedef struct {
    int data[rows][cols];
} MyStruct;

MyStruct func()
{
    MyStruct my_struct;

    // Fill my_struct.data with what you need.
    // ...

    return my_struct;
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea but it would require other changes to the code. Currently the function takes const arguments for the array dimensions like so, `CellNeighbour(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols])`. The struct must define the dimensions in its declaration so then it can't take these arguments. With this in mind, another approach I would suggest is to simply declare the array in the caller and pass it to be modified by the function.

Comment: @ChrisRollins You can't pass an array to a function. You pass a pointer to the first element of the array. So that means you're using pointers. And in turn that also means you are already using pointers in your program. Are you sure you didn't misunderstand your assignment?

Comment: right sorry. then I think there shouldn't be arguments for the array dimensions. those can be global constants.

Comment: @NikosC.Cheers man. As I said to @JohnBode . pointers were highly discouraged and my lecturer is not so strict regarding going against some parts of the assigment if it is well motivated. So I might use pointers for now. Should I then declare ``StoreArray[rows][cols]`` as pointer in my main-function and pass it to my ``CellNeighbour`` function?

Comment: if you are passing a pointer to the array, the array itself does not need to be declared as a pointer. it can be declared the way it is now. you can pass a pointer to an array to a function in order to gain access to that array.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you cannot return array types from a function.  The *right* way to do this would be to pass the target array as a parameter:

```
const int rows = 20;
const int cols = 20;
cell field[rows][cols];
int counting[rows][cols];
...
CellNeighbor( rows, cols, field, counting );
```

You'd then define your `CellNeighbor` function as:

```
void CellNeighbour(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols], int counts[rows][cols])
{
  int i,j;
  int count =0;

  // you could probably replace the following with memset( counts, 0, rows * cols * sizeof counts[0][0]
  for( i =0;i<rows;i++){
    for( j = 0;j<cols;j++){
      counts[i][i] =0;
    }
  }

  for( i =0;i<rows;i++){
    for( j = 0;j<cols;j++){
      if(field[i][j].current == ALIVE){
        counts[i][j]=count++;
      }
      if(field[i][j-1].current == ALIVE){
        counts[i][j]=count++;
      }
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Now, you're not *explicitly* using pointers anywhere, so this *should* satisfy the conditions of the assignment.

But...

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

So when you call `CellNeighbor( rows, cols, field, counting )`, the *expression* `field` is converted from type "`rows`-element array of `cols`-element array of `cell`" (`cell[rows][cols]`) to type "pointer to `cols`-element array of `cell`" (`cell (*)[cols]`).  Similarly, the expression `counting` is converted from type "`rows`-element array of `cols`-element array of `int`" (`int [rows][cols]`) to "pointer to `cols`-element array of `int`" (`int (*)[cols]`).

This means `CellNeighbor` is receiving *pointer* values for `field` and `counting`, not actual arrays.

In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are "adjusted" to `T *a`, so the declarations `cell field[row][cols]` and `int counts[row][cols]` are being interpreted as `cell field (*)[cols]` and `int counts (*)[cols]` in the `CellNeighbor` function definition.

If your assignment is serious about "no pointers", as in "no pointers AT ALL, not even implicit pointers as the result of array expression decay", then you cannot pass array expressions as function arguments, period.  I have a *really* hard time believing that's what your instructor intended.

Comment: I'm a newbie. So I might have not realized how vast pointers are. But I think he meant the usage of pointers when variables are declared as pointers and when we dereference them. But I know that we are allowed to pass array expressions as function arguments. So I might be the one to blame

Comment: @AliasaZarownyPseudonymia: this is a peculiarity of array types - the rule exists because Ritchie wanted to keep B's array semantics (C was derived from B - yes, there was a language called B), but didn't want to materialize the pointer that those semantics required, so when designing C he came up with the rule that array expressions "decay" to pointers.  No other type behaves this way.  It *is* confusing, and part of why C is a poor choice for an intro programming class.